# Get record for Indexeddb ObjectStore Where index value = 0

Tags: indexeddb

Im trying to get all records from an indexeddb store where a indexed value = 0 the below code work where the value is 1,2,3,4 etc but when its zero it dose not return.

Any ideas?

```
var rtn = [];
var keyRange = IDBKeyRange.only(value);
var txn = _internalDB.transaction(tableName, IDBTransaction.READ_ONLY);
var cursorRequest = txn.objectStore(tableName).index(field).openCursor(keyRange);

cursorRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if (cursor) {
        var res = cursor.value;
        DebugMessage('DALGetAllFromTableWhere got value');
        PrintObject(res);
        rtn.push(res);
        cursor.continue();
    }
    else {
        deferred.resolve(rtn);
    }
}

cursorRequest.onerror = function (e) {
    DebugMessage('DALGetAllFromTableWhere error' + e.message);
    deferred.reject();
};
```

Best Regards
Lmac34

Answer (score 0):

I see everything correct here. The problem is not in the code your post here.